# Наследование defineProps в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При создании классов React в es6 (хотя в принципе я не знаю решения и через API) можно определять defaultProps.

```
class MyBox extends Component {
}
myBox.defaultProps = {
    onEmptyMessage: 'Nothing at here'
}
```

Наследуя класс MyBox, мы наследуем и defaultProps.

```
class MyItems extends MyBox {
}
```

Но при попытке указать defaultProps для MyItems, defaultProps класса MyBox перезатираются.

```
MyItems.defaultProps = {
    onRemoveMessage: 'Are you sure?'
}
```

После этого onEmptyMessage, проперти от старшего класса, станет недоступно.
Конечно можно смиксовать defaultProps напрямую.

```
MyItems.defaultProps = _.extend(MyBox.defaultProps, {
    onRemoveMessage: 'Are you sure?'
});
```

Но существует ли какой-нибудь способ это сделать по замыслу React?

Comment: Ну... нет, нету. Зачем городить свой велосипед, тем более для ES6, где уже есть `Object.assign`?

Answer (score 2):

Вы наверное думаете, что это какая-то особая конструкция от `React`, но `React`, да и `es6 class` - это все тот же обычный `js` с наследованием через прототипы.

**tl;tr** Ни какого замысла `React` нет, вы все правильно делаете

`defaultProps` - статический метод класса `MyBox`. На деле же - это метод функции `MyBox` (в `js` классы=функция=объект), и поведение которое вы описываете нормально.

У вас есть первый класс `Сlass1` с методом `Class1.method`, это метод класса, не его экземпляров.
Теперь мы унаследовались от `Class1` и у нас есть `Class2` - который тоже имеет метод `Class2.method`. Теперь если мы напишем что-то вроде `Class2.method = newMethod` естественно, старая реализация перезапишется, потому что мы **просто перезаписали свойство объекта в js**.

Поэтому другого нормального способа, кроме как объединять старое св-во с новым,  нет.

Comment: если это был метод класса - он не перезапишется, он так и останется в том классе где и был

Comment: @Grundy в `Class2` он перезапишется на `newMethod`

Comment: ага, значит extends что-то еще делает, вроде он в Class2 и не должен был попасть, в любом случае прежний метод также остается доступным через базовый класс

Answer (score 1):

НИКОГДА ТАК ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НУЖНО. СЕРЬЕЗНО, НИКОГДА.

Если вам нужно как-то расширить существующий компонент, то вы делаете так...

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

class AwesomeBox extends React.Component {
  handleChange() {
    // awesom logic
  }

  render() {
    // передали все свойства и немного поменяли логику...
    return <Box {...this.props} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}
```

React проповедует композицию. Наследованию тут не место. В своем коде я вообще не использую классы ES6, именно с React это не удобно...

1. Нельзя просто взять и использовать mixins
2. Нужно биндить this для обработчиков, с React.createClass это само происходит

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тоже советовал не наследовать defaultProps, так как определение propTypes и defaultProps помогает другим разработчикам, которым достанется ваш код, сразу увидеть, какие props должны передаваться в ваш компонент. Поэтому я бы предпочёл определять их явно в каждом комоненте.